# Java.Swing BorderLayout issue

Tags: java, awt, layout-manager, border-layout

So I'm trying to get the button on the bottom right and the text field taking up the bottom left but it keeps switching around for some reason. I think its borderLayout being stupid. I'm a noob at Java btw. Here's my code:

```
package textchat;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class window extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new window();
    }

    public window()
    {

        //Window Config
        //JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension dm = tk.getScreenSize();
        this.setSize(400,400);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("CALI V1");
        this.setExtendedState(this.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        //this.setLayout(null);
        int Width = this.getWidth();


        //Panel(s)
        JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
        Panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel PanelSouth = new JPanel();
        JPanel PanelEast = new JPanel();
        JPanel PanelWest = new JPanel();
        //button
        JButton btn = new JButton("SEND");

        //Text Area
        JTextArea txt = new JTextArea(100 , 100);
        txt.setText("TEXT IS HERE");

        //Text Field
        JTextField fld = new JTextField("Type Here",15);

        //Adding to the panel
        Panel.add(txt);
        PanelSouth.add(PanelEast, BorderLayout.EAST);
        PanelSouth.add(PanelWest, BorderLayout.WEST);
        PanelEast.add(btn);
        PanelWest.add(fld);
        //adding to frame
        this.add(Panel);
        this.add(PanelSouth , BorderLayout.SOUTH);



        this.setVisible(true);



    }


}
```

Comment: You never set the layout on `PanelSouth` to be a `BorderLayout`.

Comment: ah thanks, I'm a noob at Java I knew I missed something like that. Much appreciated.

Comment: 1) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 2) `JTextArea txt = new JTextArea(100 , 100);` Note those values are columns X rows, not width X height (in pixels). 3)  Always call `pack()` after all components are added. 4) GUIs should be started on the EDT. Not doing so will cause unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

While using BorderLayout in such a way kind of works, you should
not use it in such a way. Besides, your example has several issues.
For instance, you did not start the application on the EDT (Event Dispatch Tread).

Here is a working example that creates your inteded layout. It uses the powerful `GroupLayout` manager.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TextChatEx extends JFrame {

    public TextChatEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JTextArea area = new JTextArea(15, 15);
        JTextField field = new JTextField(15);
        JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");

        createLayout(area, field, sendButton);

        setTitle("Text chat");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void createLayout(JComponent... arg) {

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
        pane.setLayout(gl);

        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        gl.setAutoCreateGaps(true);

        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[0])
                .addGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(arg[1])
                        .addComponent(arg[2]))
                );

        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[0])
                .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(arg[1])
                        .addComponent(arg[2]))                
        );

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            TextChatEx ex = new TextChatEx();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

`GroupLayout` is a powerful layout manager; with this manager, you don't have to create a bunch of panels to create some basic layout.

```
    public TextChatEx() {

        initUI();
    }
```

The GUI creation is delegated to the `initUI()` method. Rather than placing all the code into the constructor, we use a specialized method.

```
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        TextChatEx ex = new TextChatEx();
        ex.setVisible(true);
    });
```

Each Swing application should be placed on the EDT. Failing to do this can lead to hard to find bugs in the future.

[image]